# How do I have the Click event of a button manipulate another control in MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am using WPF(4.5) and Caliburn.Micro.  I am trying to understand how to have an "event" in my View manipulate other controls in my View.

For instance:

My View has an Expander Control, a Button, and a GridView.  The GridView is inside the Expander.  When the user clicks the button it calls a method in the VM that populates the gridview with a BindableCollection<>.  What I want to have happen is when that collection has more then 1 item I want to Expand the Expander Control automatically.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can bind to the number of items in a collection:

```
<Expander IsExpanded="{Binding Path=YourCollection.Length, Converter={StaticResource ResourceName=MyConverter}" />
```

and then in the window or usercontrol:

```
<UserControl... xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:My.Namespace.With.Converters">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <converters:ItemCountToBooleanConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

and the converter:

```
namespace My.Namespace.With.Converters {
    public class ItemCountToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter 
    {

        // implementation of IValueConverter here
        ...
    }
}
```

I wrote this out of my head, so apologies if it contains errors ;)

Also: Make sure your viewModel implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, but I assume you already know that.

Comment: Cool, I have not worked with Converters yet but I will look into this.

Answer (score 2):

@cguedel method is completely valid but if you don't want to use Converters (why one more class) then in your view model have another property of type `bool` maybe called ShouldExpand, well why talk so much, let me show you:

```
class YourViewModel {
    public bool ShouldExpand {
        get {
            return _theCollectionYouPopulatedTheGridWith.Length() != 0;
            // or maybe use a flag, you get the idea !
        }
    }

    public void ButtonPressed() {
        // populate the grid with collection
        // NOW RAISE PROPERTY CHANGED EVENT FOR THE ShouldExpand property
    }
}
```

Now in your View use this binding instead:

```
<Expander IsExpanded="{Binding Path=ShouldExpand}" />
```

As i said before the other solution is well but i like to reduce the number of classes in  my solutions. This is just another way of doing it.

Comment: I prefer this - either that or a you maintain a large library of reusable converters